# How to Get specific version of solution when there are multiple solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

I have multiple solutions in a folder. For example
C:\Code
    -Solution1.sln
    -Solution2.sln
    -Solution3.sln
    -[All other project files/folders belongs to above solution, etc]

Note that having these solutions in separate folders is not an option for me.

Assume if I open a one solution in VS2012 (i.e Solution1.sln). I right click on the solution 
and select Source Control -> Get Specific Version...
Select Type "Latest Version", and tick two check boxes
a. Overwrite writable files that are not checked out
b. Overwrite all files even if the local version matches

And then press the "Get" button.

The problem is that this operation gets the all the latest files for the c:\Code folder - even the ones that are not belongs to my current opened solution (Solution1.sln). It replaces the files for Solution2 and Solution3.
Is there a way I can configure TFS only to get Solution1 file?
I'm using TFS2012

Update: Please see the sample structure below.
[image]

Comment: Why don't you right click the solution file and choose get latest version (Recursive), that will update all the folders and files corresponding to the solution file. Why you chose Specific version? is your solution files share any projects? if yes it will overwrite files in other solution file.

Comment: "is your solution files share any projects?" no it doesn't. I have seen sometimes latest version(recursive) wont download the files I need so the "Get specific" option is reliable.

Comment: is your all project files inside the c:/code folder or in a a seperate folder like c:/code/project1 , c:/code/project2 ? if possible update your question with the tree structure. if you open your solution file in notepad you can see the project location. if you see same folder name in different solutions, then you have to move the project to different folder.

Comment: In regards to "is your all project files inside the c:/code folder or in a a separate folder like c:/code/project1 , c:/code/project2"?  yes the projects are in separate folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. You have to move all your solution files to a solution folder will solve your problem. TFS is trying to get all the files from the solution folder and its sub folder. That's why you having this issue. Create a folder called Solution, you can create it inside the code folder or outside. Open your solution1 file in vs2012 and select the solution file and choose File -> Save Solution1.sln as and save it in the solutions directory. Repeat the same for all the solution files.

Once you are happy with the new solution files from the solutions directory, delete the old solutions files form the code directory.

Answer (score 0):

Browse to your solution in Source Control Explorer, select "Get Specific Version" from the Advanced menu: it should work fine.